# How to change ion-select value to matching object when the value is the objects id?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a select in my code that looks like this.

```
          <ion-select formControlName="location" (click)="clearSectionAndTask()">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let location of locations" value="{{location.locationId}}">
              {{location.locationName}}
            </ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
```

The list of locations is retrieved from an API in JSON format.
The user is able to select a default location from the settings page which should then pre-select the drop down for him.

```
this.settings.getStandardLocation().then(val => {
  if (val) {
    this.formGroup.patchValue({location: val.id});
  }
});
```

Doing it like this has the expected result of changing the value of the drop down to the correct id, but doesn’t actually select and thus change the value shown on the select itself.

Doing it with patchValue({location: val}) results into the value being set to the object rather than the id.

What is the right way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: try to use '(ionChange)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to bind the value attribute use 
[value]="location.locationId"